# Does Java keep classes in the memory or just objects?

Tags: java, class, object, memory, instantiation

I'm assuming the answer is obvious, but I am new to coding and cannot find a clear answer.

Here is why I ask:  I have a "Fastball" class in a baseball game, which has 10 unique sets of data (10 difficulty levels) for a pitched fastball, and 1 blank set of data.  When an object is constructed from the class, it sets the blank set of data to 1 of the 10 data sets based on the difficulty.  Note, there is only 1 "fastball" object at any one time.

I am worried that all 10 of the data sets in this class will remain in Java's memory, even though only 1 is being used.  Is this a legitimate concern?  Or is the object the only thing that is kept in memory?

Comment: What is a _unique set of data_?

Comment: It would really help if you'd give us a short but complete example of the code you're concerned about, rather than just describing it.

Comment: Dont worry about having 10 objects :) Java will load the class and put it to the permanent generation part of jvm's memory, this will happen for every class you ever use in your code. The objects are kept on a different part of the memory(the heap) which the garbace collector will handle

Comment: @Pete: "Classes take up no memory" is not correct. They will be loaded to memory by classloaders.

Comment: @Pete once you get a permgen space exception you will see that is not correct, in fact there is a specific flag for jvm to allow unloading of classes

Comment: Yeah Classes are stored in memory and won't be purged by the garbage collection while the program is running...

Comment: It is unclear what you are describing.  You mention `Fastball` which is one class.  If you have ten _unique sets of data_ then you would probably have ten objects.  But you say there is only one object at any one time.  Is it ten or one?  Maybe it is actually eleven because you have an object for each of the ten levels and one additional object for the active level?  Or maybe you used an object reference to one of the ten, in which case you have ten.  Regardless, if you post some code then it will be more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Java will load the class and put it to the permanent generation part of jvm's memory, this will happen for every class you ever use in your code. This part is called permanent generation. Most likely you will not need to ever worry about this part, unless using application containers with hot deployment.

The objects you create are kept on a different part of the memory(actually, different generation), called the heap, divided again in different generations. The jvm will sort the objects in a way that the jvm thinks is good, and does a good job at it. Objects that get sorted in a generation of short lived objects get cleaned more aggressively, while the permanent generation usually doesn't get cleaned at all. The garbage collector will handle cleaning up after no references to these objects remain and frees the memory used.

As you have provided no code, it is hard to say how your program will work.

> I am worried that all 10 of the data sets in this class will remain in
>   Java's memory, even though only 1 is being used. Is this a legitimate
>   concern? Or is the object the only thing that is kept in memory?

Depends on if you keep references to these fastball objects. If you keep reference to one fastball object at a time, the garbage collector will eventually clean up the unreferenced objects.

Answer (score 0):

If your data sets are instances of the class Fastball they will remain in memory until they are no longer referenced. If your program no longer references them then garbage collection will free up the memory associated with those objects. If your program constantly maintains a reference to them, then they will remain in memory.

Unless the data stored by your Fastball class is very large, having 10 Fastball objects in memory shouldn't be a problem. If instead the data is very large you could store the data in separate files and read it into a single instance of the Fastball class and just overwrite the reference for this instance every time you wanted to load a new instance from the disk. This makes it so that the program only maintains a single Fastball reference in memory, so the previous instance will be removed from memory by garbage collection.

Note that your program will be significantly slower though since it will have to load the information from the disk prior to using it.